# R: Calculating difference between proportions for categorical data

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a dataset comparing `yes`/`no` data for options `A`/`B`/`C`/`D`. I want to work out the proportions of each option `A`/`B`/`C`/`D` that are `yes`, and work out the absolute and relative difference in proportion compared to the proportion of `A` that are `yes`.

If there's a more efficient way to get to this relative and absolute change in proportions compared to a reference proportion, I would be really interested to hear about that too! So far, I've been using `dplyr`, I'm happy to use another library if it achieves the desired result.

**Data:**

My data is in the following format:

```
> str ( df )
'data.frame':   589 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ grp1: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 3 1 2 1 3 3 4 2 2 1 ...
 $ grp2: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
>
> table ( df )
    grp2
grp1   N   Y
   A  81  40
   B 144  61
   C 117  38
   D  88  20
```

**Proportions:**

I've calculated the proportions of `yes`/(`yes` + `no`) as follows:

```
>library ( dplyr )
> df %>%
+      group_by ( grp1 , grp2 ) %>%
+      summarise ( n = n () ) %>% 
+      mutate ( total = sum ( n ) ) %>%
+      mutate ( prop = n / sum ( n ) ) %>% 
+      filter ( grp2 == "Y" )
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   grp1 [4]
  grp1  grp2      n total prop
  <fct> <fct> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 A     Y        40   121 0.331
2 B     Y        61   205 0.298
3 C     Y        38   155 0.245
4 D     Y        20   108 0.185
```

**What I want:**

Hard coded, `difference.absolute` = `prop` - 0.331, `difference.relative` = `prop` / 0.331.
I want the code to use the first value of the `prop` column as the reference value, rather than have me specify the reference value manually.

```
  grp1  grp2      n  total   prop  difference.absolute  difference.relative
1 A     Y        40    121  0.331                    0                    1
2 B     Y        61    205  0.298              -0.0334                0.899
3 C     Y        38    155  0.245              -0.0858                0.741
4 D     Y        20    108  0.185               -0.146                0.559
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df %>%
  group_by ( grp1 , grp2 ) %>%
  summarise ( n = n () ) %>% 
  mutate ( total = sum ( n ) ) %>%
  mutate ( prop = n / sum ( n ) ) %>% 
  filter ( grp2 == "Y" ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(difference.absolute = prop - prop[1]) %>% 
  mutate(difference.relative = prop / prop[1])
```

Comment: Something like that, yes. But, if I add those two commands onto the end of my pipe, I get "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `difference.absolute`.
x Input `difference.absolute` can't be recycled to size 1.
ℹ Input `difference.absolute` is `prop - df$prop[1]`.
ℹ Input `difference.absolute` must be size 1, not 0.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: grp1 = "A".'

Comment: @Ged dplyr is trying to apply the operation group-wise. Try to add a `ungroup()` step before.

Comment: @WiktorGustafsson, adding `ungroup() %>%` after my code/before `mutate(difference.absolute = prop - df$prop[1])` gives me `Input 'difference.absolute' can't be recycled to size 4.`

Comment: I've worked it out! Your solution, @WiktorGustafsson and @ornaldo_, but referring to `df` as `.` inside the `mutate()` instead

Comment: @Ged Great! But I thnk you can skip that entirely and just reference the variables directly - i.e. just `prop` instead of `.$prop`. It should know that the scope is `df`.

Comment: @WiktorGustafsson you're right! `mutate(difference.absolute = prop - prop[1])` also works as expected

Answer (score 3):

simplifying your syntax a bit

```
df %>% count(grp1, grp2) %>%
  group_by(grp1) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(n),
         prop = n/total) %>%
  filter(grp2 == "Y") %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(difference.absolut = prop - first(prop),
         difference.relative = prop/first(prop))

# A tibble: 4 x 7
  grp1  grp2      n total  prop difference.absolut difference.relative
  <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>              <dbl>               <dbl>
1 A     Y        40   121 0.331             0                    1    
2 B     Y        61   205 0.298            -0.0330               0.900
3 C     Y        38   155 0.245            -0.0854               0.742
4 D     Y        20   108 0.185            -0.145                0.560
```